# Attributes vs Properties in Fable Elmish

Tags: fable-f#, elmish

I am going through the book "Elm in Action" and trying to convert the application developed there to Fable-Elmish.  Many things translate directly from Elm to Elmish but not everything (at least not directly).  Right now I am trying to understand how to set properties on custom HTML element in Fable-Elmish.  The book has an example of a [JS Range](https://github.com/mm-jsr/jsr) object with the following script in the HTML file:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://elm-in-action.com/range-slider.css">
<script src="http://elm-in-action.com/range-slider.js"></script>
<script>
  class RangeSlider extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      var input = document.createElement("input");
      this.appendChild(input);

      var jsr = new JSR(input, {
        max: this.max,
        values: [this.val],
        sliders: 1,
        grid: false
      });
    }
  }

  window.customElements.define("range-slider", RangeSlider);
</script>
```

The Elm code to initialize this looks like this:

```
rangeSlider attributes children =
  node "range-slider" attributes children

viewFilter name magnitude =
  div [ class "filter-slider" ]
      [ label [] [ text name ]
      , rangeSlider
          [ max "11"
          , Html.Attributes.property "val" (Json.Encode.int magnitude)
          ]
          []
      , label [] [ text (String.fromInt magnitude) ]
]
```

The portion I am having trouble understanding is the difference between the `max` and `HTML.Attributes.property` attributes, and how to translate them into Fable-Elmish.

I have a similar block in my Elmish code that looks like this:

```ml
let rangeSlider attributes children =
  domEl "range-slider" attributes children

let viewFilter name magnitude =
  ... // other elements
  rangeSlider [ Max "11"
                HTMLAttr.Custom ("val", Encode.int magnitude)
              ] []
  ...
```

But this doesn't appear to be correct.  I believe that `domEl` is the equivalent to `node` in Elm.  I only found the `Custom` constructor and `domEl` function by trolling through the sources (the docs seem to be woefully lacking).

In the original Elm code it makes a distinction between `max` as an attribute and `val` as a property.  It would appear that I am setting `val` as an attribute as well instead of a property.  Is that the case?  If so, how do I set the property correctly?